# Heart sprite not being drawn

Tags: java, swing

So I've been trying to make a sprite object (called heart) that can be moved around by players on the JPanel "Battle box". Very similar code has worked for me in the past but weirdly not now. I need to clarify, this is PART of a project, not the whole thing. The BattleBox JPanel object gets called from a different part of the program, though technically it's possible the error isn't within these classes

Also btw not all the code is written for the new ones since I need to make it appear first before I can start making it move around and such xD Anyway any help people can give is appreciated and, just in case it wasn't obvious, I'm self taught and bad so sorry if the answer's super obvious

Also slight side note, the clock also doesn't show but I've kinda accepted fate with that one for now

**Battle screen class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import MainMenu.MainMenu;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BattleScreen extends JPanel {

    private Heart heart;
    private Thread thread;
    private Clock clock;
    
    public BattleScreen() {
        
        this.setBounds(0, 0, MainMenu.frame.getWidth(), MainMenu.frame.getHeight());
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        clock = new Clock(this);
        
        heart = new Heart();
        heart.allowMovement(true);
        
        MainMenu.con.add(this);
        this.repaint();
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                repaint();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        heart.draw(g, this);
        clock.draw(g, this);
    }
}
```

**Heart class**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Heart {
    
    int xPos, yPos, width, height;
    Thread thread;
    BufferedImage image;

    public Heart() {
        
        width = 44;
        height = 44;
        xPos = (MainMenu.MainMenu.con.getWidth() - width) / 2;
        yPos = (MainMenu.MainMenu.con.getHeight() - height) / 2;
        
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/BattleScreen/heart.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.repaint();
        
        thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
            updateMovement();
        }};
    }
    
    void draw (Graphics g, Component c) {
        g.drawImage(image, xPos, yPos, width, height, c);
    }
}
```

**Classes that worked in the past:**

**OLD BattleScreen**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import MainMenu.MainMenu;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BattleScreen extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private static JFrame frame = MainMenu.frame;
    static Heart sprite = new Heart(frame.getWidth()/2, frame.getHeight()/2, 20, 20);
    
    public BattleScreen() {
        
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        
        setBounds(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        setBackground(Color.black);
        MainMenu.con.add(this);
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                sprite.updateMovement();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        sprite.draw(g, this);
    }
}
```

**OLD Heart class**

```
package DEADBattleScreen;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Heart {

    Image img;
    int xPos, yPos, width, height;
    Thread thread;
    
    Heart(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/battlescreen/heart.png"));
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    void draw (Graphics g, Component c) {
        g.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos, width, height, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I need to clarify, this is PART of a project, not the whole thing."* Don't post part, don't post all. Post an MRE / SSCCE. Or to put that another way: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: @AndrewThompson updated to exclude irrelevant methods, attributes and such

Comment: There should be one `main` method in one `public` class. The other classes need to be default access so they can be added into the same source code file as a the `main` class.